# How to get a string's order number in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's an array:

```
var array = new Array();
array[0] = "sound1.mp3"
array[1] = "sound2.mp3"
array[2] = "sound3.mp3"
```

In a function that I've written, I need to get the string's order number.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
function registerSound(array, i) {
    var arrno = ???;
    var arrurl = array[i];

    soundManager.createSound({ id: 'sound' + arrno, url: arrurl });
}

function processArray(array) {;
    for(i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
         registerSound(array, i);
    }
}
```

The `arrno` variable should have the order number of `"sound2.mp3"` (in this case `1`). It needs to be set up so that, when the `for` statement turns to the next string in the array, the `arrno` variable will contain the order number of `"sound3.mp3"` (2).

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Um, isn't that just your `i` variable?

Comment: wouldn't that just be `i` in your example?

Comment: yes I don't get it...it's the i var!

Comment: check above...the knights who say "i", ;-)

Comment: `i` = **url**. I need the _order number_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function registerSound(array, i) {
    var arrurl = array[i];
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'sound' + i,
        url: arrurl
    });
}
```

Also, declare your variables and start your loop from `0`:

```
function processArray(array) {;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        registerSound(array, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: lol, it's not that 500 people stated this in the comment section;)

Comment: @Christoph I am laughing hysterically